# Error to replace fragment by Listfragment

Tags: android

I did this

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment obj = null;
    ListFragment listfragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            listfragment= new F1_fr();
            break;
        case 1:
            obj= new F6_fr();
            break;
        case 2:
            obj= new F3_fr();
            break;
        case 3:
            obj= new F4_fr();
            break;
        case 4:
            obj= new F5_fr();
            break;
    }

    if (obj != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, obj)
            .commit();
    }
    else if (listfragment != null) {
        // do stuff if its a listfragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, listfragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

But i have an error here : .replace(R.id.container, listfragment) 
that said me replace android.supportv4.app.fragment in fragment transaction cannot be applied to(int, android.app.ListFragment)

```
    public class F1_fr extends ListFragment {
   View rootview;
    TextView t;
    ListView listView;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.f1_lay,container,false);
        listView =(ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.semi_transparent).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), qr.class);
                ;

                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });



        return rootview;

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heroes);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        setListAdapter(aa);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `android.app` fragments with support library fragments.

Since your intention seems to be using support library fragments, replace your `android.app` fragment imports such as `android.app.ListFragment` with their support library counterparts such as `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`.

Comment: I have no longer the error thank you but now i have this error when i try to open the fragment and it crashed "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Comment: That's quite obvious, isn't it?

Comment: If you override `onCreateView()` in a `ListFragment`, the returned view must include a `ListView` with that id.

Comment: Yep but i did this but i dont understand why it crashed look at the post i added the fragment code

Comment: @BtAndro  I get the same error, java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' , guys did any of you has resolved this?

Comment: android:id="@id/android:list" in the xml file for the fragment and also there,s no need to instantiate the listView in the method onCreateView, the inflate is enough.

Answer (score 2):

When you automatically optimize your imports (like Ctrl-Shift-O in Eclipse), the system should give you a choise what Fragment to import. Choose a support version or a ListFragment like laalto said.